# Prevent ViewController from stacking in the background when created with present

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I use this code to open a new ViewController:

```
// Get a random next post
@IBAction func buttonNextPostTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let postNumber = Int.random(in: 0 ..< postIds.count)
    let postId = postIds[postNumber]

    PostApi.shared.getPost(postId: postId) { (post) in
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainApplication", bundle: nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostsViewController") as! PostsViewController
        nextViewController.post = post
        nextViewController.isFromRandom = true
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
}
```

This code will open the same ViewController with different data. It works, however, the "old" ViewControllers will stack in the background. So if I open 10 new ViewControllers, I have 10 VC in the background.

How can I present a new ViewController, and dismiss the "old" one?

Comment: You cannot dismiss a view controller unless it is a modal

Answer (score 0):

Using `setViewControllers` function from `UINavigationController` is the best way.

```
func setViewControllers(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController], animated: Bool)
```

And you can remove whichever controller you want to from stack like

```
 if var navigationControllersArray:Array = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers) {
            navigationControllersArray.remove(at: navigationControllersArray.count-2)
            self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationControllersArray
        }
```